# \n in INSTR SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, heidisql

When I make a

```
(select instr(hist.texte, '\n'))
```

I find 0 while there is \n in my text.

I don't have this error with another character chain.

Is it the "\" which could be a problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you have in text? `\n` literally, as typed? Or line breaks?

Comment: Typed, in this type : "doublon\nPas de rendez-vous pris." When there is a "." or line breaks before \n it works but not in the character chain above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're speaking about text, literally typed in your string, then you should escape `\n` since DBMS will treat `\` as escape-sequence symbol. So following will work:

```
SELECT INSTR(hist.texte, '\\n')
```